# PasswordBox placeholder text isn't returning when cleared

Tags: c#, uwp, placeholder, passwordbox

So I have a `PasswordBox`:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwbPassword" PlaceholderText="Password" 
             Password="{x:Bind Path=local:Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

However I also have a clear function which contains:

```
Password = null
```

The issue I am having is that the `PlaceholderText` isn't being reinstated and instead the box is left blank.

Is this a bug or am I missing somthing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PasswordBox placeholder text isn't returning when cleared

I check your code, `Password` is string property, please bind with string field.

```
<PasswordBox

    Name="MyPassswordBox"
    Height="44"
    MaxLength="20"
    Password="{x:Bind PassWord, Mode=TwoWay}"
    PlaceholderText="Input your Password"
    />
```

**Code behind**

```
private string _passWord;

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }
 public string PassWord
 {

     get { return _passWord; }
     set
     {
         _passWord = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();

     }
 }
```

If you want clear password, please set `PassWord` as null.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PassWord = null;
}
```

I have tested, the PlaceholderText will be reinstated.